# How to get actual content/body from httpRequestMessage in java azure function

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, azure-functions

I am developing one java azure function to upload files or images

```
@FunctionName("upload")
public HttpResponseMessage uploadDocuments(@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {
HttpMethod.POST }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<String> request,final ExecutionContext context){
// Get request body 
String reqBody = request.getBody().get(); 
}
```

//Here i am getting reqBody like this it inclued headers with content

```
----------------------------493134179411177203860920
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile[]"; filename="newone.json"
Content-Type: application/json

{
"name":"jhon"
 "age":23
}

----------------------------493134179411177203860920--
```

Actual file content

```
{
    "name":"jhon"
     "age":23
    }
```

Question: is there any way to get the content without headers using httpRequestMessage in java ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Is there any way to get the content without headers using `httpRequestMessage` in java?
```

No, we cannot get only the content without headers using the `httpRequestMessage` in java.

There is no method inside `httpRequestMessage` interface which can be used to remove the headers present inside the **RequestBody**, But there are few methods by using which we can get only the **headers** present inside the HTTP Request.

Refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.functions.httprequestmessage?view=azure-java-stable#methods) for more information.